# Padding a char with 0s in C

Tags: c, string, char, padding

I am trying to pad a certain amount of zeros to the beginning of a char array, which is to be later read as ints. Here is my code:

```
// charArray is '123' right now
// want charArray to be 00123
// Shift elements in array forward 'difference' times
// difference is amount of 0s to be padded to beginning of string, difference = 2 here
for (i = strlen(charArray) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    charArray[i+difference] = charArray[i];
}
```

This is where I have problems. The way the code below runs, `charArray` is `??123`

```
for (i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
    y[i] = 0 - '0';
}
```

If I do this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
    y[i] = 0;
}
```

My string gets terminated early. Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you assign an integer to a pointer?

Comment: `harArray = 123; //int value is 123 right now` – This is not how it works.  Have a look at [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: That is not the actual assignment, just the value of `charArray` at the current time.

Comment: @MortalMan It sure looks like actual assignment.

Comment: Whatever you want that statement to do, it does not.

Comment: Okay, what is `0 - '0'`? (hint: –48)

Answer (score 1):

To set the padding area, just use this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
    charArray[i] = '0';
}
```

or possibly:

```
memset(charArray, '0', difference);
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks for actually helping me and not trying to rip apart my code :)

Comment: @MortalMan: More helpful remarks: make sure `i` is signed, not `size_t`, and `charArray` is large enough to accomodate the string, the extra padding and the final `'\0'`.  Both definitions are missing.

Comment: after I shift the string, I should manually place `'\0` at the end of the string, right?

Comment: @MortalMan: of course you do.  The easy way to do this is to not subtract `1` from `strlen(charArray)` in the `for` loop.  This `-1` is actually a bug.

Comment: I don't add a '\0' after this code, and the code works fine: `memmove(y+difference, y, strlen(y));
memset(y, '0', difference);` should I be concerned?

Comment: @MortalMan: yes you should.  It only works by chance, because there is a `'\0'` in the array already.  Don't rely on this coincidence, use this: `memmove(y + difference, y, strlen(y) + 1);`

Comment: Thanks , I was having issues relating to this and the +1 fixed it. What does the +1 do?

Comment: @MortalMan: you want `memmove` to shift all the characters in `y` **plus** the `'\0'` trailing byte, hence `strlen(y) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If your originally allocated array is big enough to hold both the original string, it's null terminator, and the padding together, then you can do this:

```
memmove(charArray+difference, charArray, strlen(charArray));
memset(charArray, '\0', difference);
```

If you are shifting a string that doesn't have the extra allocate bytes, then some characters are going to get dropped.  Hence:

Shift a **string** by N "difference" bytes and pad the leading space with zeros

```
int original_array_size = strlen(charArray) + 1;
memmove(charArray+difference, charArray, original_array_size-difference);
memset(charArray, '\0', difference);
charArray[original_array_size - 1] = '\0'; // assumes original_array_size is >= 1
```

Comment: What is `(int)charArray = 123;` supposed to do?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: @5gon12eder  - that's the test value that the OP was using in his example.  I wasn't exactly sure how his statement of `charArray = 123` was supposed to actually work, but it didn't look right.

Comment: I also think it should be `memmove(charArray+difference, charArray, array_size - difference);`.

Comment: @selbie OP has edited the question meanwhile. I think it was meant to be a comment saying that `strcmp("123", charArray) == 0`.

Comment: @5gon12eder - No, because I deliberately allocate the array to be "array_size+difference" such that the entire array could be shifted safely.  If he wants to shift the array and lose the trailing bytes at the end, then you are correct.

Comment: Given the OP's changes, I rewrote my answer.  More details coming.

Comment: @selbie The `memmove` call works perfectly, but `memset` seems to be ending my string early.

Comment: @selbie I believe the right call is `memset(charArray, '0', difference);`

Comment: @MortalMan - Change the memset call to be `memset(charArray, '0', difference);`  Notice the subtle difference.

Comment: @selbie Yep, I was 4 second ahead of you ;)

Comment: Your question was ambiguous.  You didn't indicate if you wanted to pad the array with "leading zero characters" or "null bytes".  "Pad with zero's" typically means the latter in most circles.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is the character you are setting. In the first case you use `y[i] = 0 - '0';` which will give you a character value of -48, which will be a byte of hex 0xD0. This is a character in the extended ascii range which is why you are getting a peculiar character there.

In the second case you used `y[i] = 0;` Which is a byte value of zero which is used as a zero terminator (hence the early termination of your string).

What you want to use is `y[i] = '0';`